# No data over json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, grails

I am using `angularjs 1.2.8` with `grails 2.3.4` backend. I am providing a Restful Api over the grails `Resources` tag.

I have a view were I load the data:

```
<div class="container main-frame" ng-app="testapp"
    ng-controller="searchController" ng-init="init()">
    <h1 class="page-header">Products</h1>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="25px">ID</th>
                <th>TITLE</th>
                <th>PRICE</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th width="50px"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="p in product by $id">
                <td>{{p.id}}</td>
                <td>{{p.title}}</td>
                <td>{{p.price}}</td>
                <td>{{p.description}}</td>
                <!-- ng-show="user.id &&user.id==e.user_id" -->
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!-- ng-show="user.username" -->
    <p>
</div>
```

I am using the `searchController` to load the data:

```
testapp.controller("searchController", function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location) {
  var load = function() {
    console.log('call load()...');

    var url = 'products.json';

    if ($rootScope && $rootScope.appUrl) {
      url = $rootScope.appUrl + '/' + url;
    }

    $http.get(url)
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.product = data;
        angular.copy($scope.product, $scope.copy);
      });
  }

  load();
});
```

However in my postgresql db there is data available, but I only get:

[image]

and no expection at all:

[image]

Any suggestions what I can do to check that?

PS.: Controller is loaded!

**UPDATE**

Using

```
<tr ng-repeat="p in product track by p.id">
```

I am getting an error:

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.8/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=p%20in%20product%20track%20by%20p.id&p1=undefined
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js:6:449
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js:184:445
    at Object.fn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js:99:371)
    at h.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js:100:299)
    at h.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js:103:100)
    at f (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js:67:98)
    at E (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js:71:85)
    at XMLHttpRequest.v.onreadystatechange (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js:72:133) angular.js:9413
```

**UPDATE2**

The json representation looks like that:

> `[{"class":"com.testapp.Product.BasicProduct","id":1,"dateCreated":"2014-02-17T13:43:13Z","description":"blblblblbalablablalbalbablablablablblabalalbllba","lastUpdated":"2014-02-17T13:43:13Z","price":5.0,"title":"Product1"},{"class":"com.testapp.Product.BasicProduct","id":2,"dateCreated":"2014-02-17T13:43:13Z","description":"blblblblbalablablalbalbablablablablblabalalbllba","lastUpdated":"2014-02-17T13:43:13Z","price":75.0,"title":"Product2"},{"class":"com.testapp.Product.BasicProduct","id":3,"dateCreated":"2014-02-17T13:43:13Z","description":"blblblblbalablablalbalbablablablablblabalalbllba","lastUpdated":"2014-02-17T13:43:13Z","price":50.0,"title":"Product3"},{"class":"com.testapp.Product.BasicProduct","id":4,"dateCreated":"2014-02-17T13:43:13Z","description":"blblblblbalablablalbalbablablablablblabalalbllba","lastUpdated":"2014-02-17T13:43:13Z","price":25.0,"title":"Product4"},{"class":"com.testapp.Product.BasicProduct","id":5,"dateCreated":"2014-02-17T13:43:13Z","description":"blblblblbalablablalbalbablablablablblabalalbllba","lastUpdated":"2014-02-17T13:43:13Z","price":15.0,"title":"Product5"}]`

Comment: Can you show a JSON representation of your data (products) ? I though that id is a unique key

Comment: Check your data to see if there are undefined ids -> this is what the dupes error means.

Comment: @IlanFrumer Thx for your answer! The thing is I have pasted all the data that is currently available in the db...

Comment: Look at this example : http://plnkr.co/edit/3IXThMzP1iOe7eZI1oUc?p=preview . same data you provided works fine. Maybe your server returns a wrapped data, please `console.log(data)` in the success callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the `ngRepeat` syntax:

```
<tr ng-repeat="p in product track by p.id">
```

Comment: Ok thx for your help and support. I found the error after sleeping one night over it. Is was a simple `s` in the json url ;(